# echo'ing XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

why wont the following echo out the strings?

```
    <?php

    header("Content=type: text/xml");

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" ?>';
    echo '<strains>';
    echo '<strainName>';
    echo '</strainName>';
    echo '</strains>';


    ?>
```

Basically I am experimenting with php and xml and noticed that when i create this script and run it, nothing is outputed to the screen?

Comment: Is it the only code used or is this part of a larger page of coding? If it's the only code, I don't know what you're trying to achieve but you could check the page source (on the page that you say is blank).

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the generated *source*? Try "view source" in your browser.

Comment: yea it shows correctly in the view source. so it basically made the elements but did not display in browser. thank you didnt think of that brain fart moment.

Comment: It didn't display because it's not valid HTML, and the browser tries to render the invalid tags by default, thus outputs nothing. You need to make it aware that the content is XML, not HTML. See [Vikram's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9346411/732284).

Comment: What is your browser? Remember that Chrome doesn't display XML like Firefox.

Comment: yea its the building block to a larger chunk of code. just trying to get a better understanding so i started simple

Comment: i have it working the way i want it to now.  thank you everybody for the response. very helpful thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of MIME type is incorrect. It should be:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

Comment: oops yea i didn't even realize that typo thank you. Been driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. 
Open your php.ini and set the option

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

After that, restart your server.

Comment: `<?` might be parsed as the beginning of a short PHP tag (`<? echo 'a'; ?>`).

Comment: I've the same problem one year ago and was for that. Also I try his source and works fine in my server.

Comment: THank you for your response. i appreciate all the help on here.